# How do I create a method to find out if a user is part of a group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, model-associations

I am having a hard time creating a method to find out if a user is part of a group. There is a model for User, Group, and Membership. Below are two methods (of the many that I attempted but to no success).

**How can I create a method to find out if a user is a member of a group?** (I would like the method to produce a true or false result.)

```
def member?(group_1)
  if Membership.where(user_id: self.id, group_id: group_1.id)
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end

def membership?(group)
  Membership.where(user_id: self.id, group_id: group.id)
end
```

Here are the attributes of the three different models:

```
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "group_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
end
```

**Here is the code in each respective model:**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards to you question ***create a method to find out if a user is a member of a group***,  This should work fine

In `user.rb` define an instance method

```
def membership?(group)
  memberships.find_by(group: group).present?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
def member?(group)
  groups.include?(group)
end
```

Comment: Thank you @dhouty! This method works. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your current membership? method is returning an array. If you append .any? to the end of it, it will return true or false.

```
def membership?(group)
  Membership.where(user_id: self.id, group_id: group.id).any?
end
```

EDIT: dhouty's answer is the most precise - leaving this here just to explain why your original method wasn't working

Comment: ha, i just said similiar thing to him :P

Answer (score 0):

not the answer, but just saying:

```
def member?(group_1)
  if Membership.where(user_id: self.id, group_id: group_1.id)
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Membership.where will  `return []` unless it finds any data. For that, `[] does equal  true` , that means - your true block will always be called! If you wanna stick with that where logic, you need to ask if the array is containing any data. `[].any?`

you dont need to write `return` since ruby is always returning the last value of anything.

**// Edit towards your request by comment:**

ya, you can go .where().any? but imageine the .where() will return a thousand datasets and you just need to know if there is just one... 
We would call this "bad code".

The better solution would be to use find_by. Find_by returns the first matching element. 
`Membership.find_by(user_id: id, group_id. group_1.id)`

the good thing about `find_by` is the fact, that it will return `nil` if nothing was found. That means you can do this

```
def member?(group_1)
    !!Membership.find_by(user_id: id, group_id: group_1.id)
end
```

Find_by will return nil or the object, with `!!` you make the object to an expression of `true`

Comment: Thank you @huan son for this insight. I was curious to know why my method was returning the data and not true or false. Now I learned about the code ".any? "

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two clean ways. (You may either or both use the following)

1) app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # ...
  def member_of_group?(group)
    groups.exists?(group)
  end
end
```

2) app/models/groups.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  # ...
  def has_user_member?(user)
    users.exists?(user)
  end
end
```

Then you can just use the methods like the following:

```
# If checking if a User object is member of a @group
@user.member_of_group?(@group)
=> returns true or false

# If checking if a Group object has a member @user
@group.has_user_member?(@user)
=> returns true or false
```